# Auto-Switch-Context between a list of fibers

Tags: c++, windows, operating-system, fiber

Is there a way to implement system like OS that allocates time for each process\thread with fibers?
I mean like when I run a process and do an infinite loop inside it, the OS can still function normal on one core. (It switch context automatically without the process's permission or order)

I don't have internal functions that the fibers use that I can check the time and switch-context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, sure there is, the OS does it. Although doing it yourself in your own process without using the OS services is a bit hard.

There was an old book, called [Born to Code in C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0078814685) by Herbert Schildt, that had a rudimentary multi-threading mechanism implemented in C and running in the same process.

Comment: That looks like a lot of work, expected a function that switches context from a second thread. (Outside of the targeted thread) I'll wait a bit, thanks.

Comment: The OS does that automatically for you. You don't switch between threads at all. If you want to switch between fibers - you need to specify the OS.

Comment: I thought OS gave support to switch context from outside at least. (Searched before at Google but didn't found)

Comment: You can't tell the OS to switch threads of any process. If your OS supports fibers, you can switch fibers - but only from within the process.

Comment: That's what I am getting at, I can't switch context ordered from another thread? (Inside the same process)

Comment: What is it you're *actually* trying to accomplish?

Comment: I work on Data Mining program that constantly "thinking" about a way to interpret data and it can be 4 loops inside each other and I can't check if the time is over each iteration. (Performance problems) But I need sometimes to receive new data, then I need a way to allocate work and switch. (Or something similar)

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen when you receive new data?  Why can't it be done in a separate thread?

Comment: @HarryJohnston This is a mass of data (A lot of data that is recursively) I have two options: Spinlock every resource that it'll be slow do a 3ms of thinking and 3ms time to receive data. That's one problem in my program, hard to make it multithreading.

Comment: We need to know what the problem is, not what you think the solutions are.  Why do you need to "spinlock every resource", and why would this be a problem using threads if it wouldn't be a problem using fibers?  Would it work if you suspended the processing thread while another thread updated the data?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Like I said this is a mass of data that is connected to each other but not necessary contains. (This isn't hierarchy data) I can think of problems when you suspend a thread in this program. I just want to say that the program isn't fully developed. (But the design is somehow complete)

Comment: Even if you could forcibly switch away from a fiber (which you can't) the effect would be identical to suspending a thread.  So I don't think using fibers is going to help you here, and you're going to have to put some kind of test inside your data processing loops.  If you're unsure how to do so efficiently, I recommend asking another question.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I think you are right on this one. I thought give a function that'll have (1/1024)% chance to do switch context. I'll call it inside loops or where it'll be "safe" to dispatch.

Comment: You can probably just test a variable declared with the `volatile` keyword.  The change won't kick in immediately because of memory caching, but the delay should be short (by human standards, anyway).

Comment: @HarryJohnston I have a lot of thoughts\fibers so I think I'll stick to the chance thing. Thanks I think I'll use those methods to the inner thoughts\fibers.